# jQuery trigger click on focus, but not if clicked to focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, material-design-lite

I am working on an [MDL](https://getmdl.io/) site.  There is [known issue](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/854) that they still don't give a default `select` form element.  The solution I found was to use a [menu component](https://getmdl.io/components/#menus-section), which will show when the `input` is clicked.  Works well.  But I noticed that the menu will not show up when the input is focused using the TAB key.  So I put this in jQuery:

```
/*
Make menus show up on input focus
*/
$('.mdl-textfield__input').focus(function(){
    $(this).click();
});
```

This works well for showing the menu on TAB driven focus.  But the problem is that now when I click on the input, it will show and then hide the menu.  The real click shows it and the next simulated click from my code will cause it to close.

I am wondering if I can tell if the focus state was driven by a click or not, and condition my jQuery code on that.  So if the focus was driven from a click then I don't need to simulate the click?

Here is an example of the MDL HTML code:

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label {% if form.errors.gender %}is-invalid{% endif %}">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="gender">Gender</label>
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" id="id_gender" name="gender" type="text" readonly value="{{ form.gender.value }}" readonly>
    <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect select-menu" for="id_gender">
        <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="m">Male</li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="f">Female</li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="t">Transgender</li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="o">Other</li>
    </ul>
    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ form.errors.gender.as_text }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('focus', '.mdl-textfield__input', function(e){
    $(this).trigger('click')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with a Drupal Superfish mobile menu and found the answer here [Detect if focus event was triggered by user/browser or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726814/detect-if-focus-event-was-triggered-by-user-browser-or-jquery)

That answer specifically works for clicks, but you can rework for either. Should be something like this:

```
var isUserClick = false;
$('.mdl-textfield__input').mousedown(function(){
   isUserClick = true;
});
$('.mdl-textfield__input').focus(function(e){
  if (isUserClick === false){
    $(this).click();
  } else {
    isUserClick = false;
  }
});
```