# Detect if focus event was triggered by user/browser or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to detect if focus event was triggered by user (manually).
When it comes to the `click` event, it is possible to check if `event.originalEvent` is present inside handler method:

```
typeof event.originalEvent != "undefined"
```

Unfortunately, it behaves different for focus event.
Please check the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/trdyg8sb/4/).

Try to click on the first `<input>` and then click on "trigger click" button for the second input, you will see `click undefined`, what means that the `event.originalEvent` is not present.
Then try to click on the first `<input>` followed by the click on "trigger focus" button for the second input, you will see `focus object`, `event.originalEvent` is present this time.

- How to detect if focus event was triggered by user (not programmatically)?

Comment: This maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653332/differentiate-between-focus-event-triggered-by-keyboard-mouse

Comment: Can you use special events? like `custom_blur` as alias for `blur`?

Comment: Under chrome (not tested with other browsers) "event.originalEvent.sourceCapabilities" is null when triggered from the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply `mousedown` event to check if it's user action or not:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var isUserClick = false;
  $("input").mousedown(function() {
    isUserClick = true;
  });
  $("input").on("click focus blur", function(event) {
    console.log(event.type, typeof event.originalEvent, isUserClick ? 'user' : 'script');
    setTimeout(function() {
      isUserClick = false;
    }, 200);
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("input." + $(this).attr("class")).trigger($(this).data("event"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
FIRST:
<input class="first" />
<button class="first" data-event="click">trigger click</button>
<button class="first" data-event="focus">trigger focus</button>
<button class="first" data-event="blur">trigger blur</button>
<br>
<br> SECOND:
<input class="second" />
<button class="second" data-event="click">trigger click</button>
<button class="second" data-event="focus">trigger focus</button>
<button class="second" data-event="blur">trigger blur</button>
<br>
```

Comment: Warning, it only catch "click" accesses, it does not take account of jumping into the field using the tab key.